# how do you turn the overfow drain in tub upside down

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

my house was built in 1946, love the old tub but how do I turn the overflow drain upside down where I may take a bath? As of right now, there's not enough water to cover my feet! Here are the images, sorry about the mess! I plan on replacing the knobs, etc..[overflow[image: knobs are going to be replaced] The tub itself will be re-caulked also

Comment: Until you get the lever controlled stopper to work, you might be able to stop it with a thin, flat rubber (elastomer) stopper.

Comment: Since this does seem to be about changing the overflow level, at the risk of making it essentially a shopping question, there is a product for exactly that purpose that involves no actual plumbing - a clear plastic dome with suction cups and a hole - you turn the hole to set your new desired overflow level, and then you have to be very careful in the bath or you'll slop water over the edge onto the floor. "overflow drain cover" should find it without getting into spamming a brand name, of which there seem to be several selling the same thing.

Comment: I glued a shaped piece of brass over the bottom half of the inlet to my overflow drain. That got me another 1.5 inches if depth. Tested to see that flow through overflow drain was strong enough to take hot and cold at full throttle. You do NOT want your tub overflowing onto the floor. That sort of thing causes ceilings to collapse.

Comment: Thanks so Much everyone!! Co-workers husband turned it for me, Sorry I haven't been on here, but thanx A Bunch!

Comment: @jonib, please provide and accept an answer, accept one of the others offered, or delete your post. We'd like to see this question resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but If read this correctly, it is not a case of it not working properly, it is a case of the water level in the tub being to shallow ( reaching the overflow before it covers her toes.) As lover of soaking in a tub i sympathize with her and wish for her to have a deep soaking tub, but short of a new tub there is not much one can do.

I believe she is asking how to change the Height of the overflow opening to allow the water level in the tub to be deeper.

The opening is on the underside of the chrome overflow escutcheon, You could try and take off the escutcheon,  put a wash cloth over the drain so you do not drop the screws down the drain. (three screws, two for the cover one for the handle, take the handle of first then take the escutcheon cover off) turn the escutcheon 180 degrees so that the opening is on top. you would have to caulk around the bottom. This would result in gain of maybe in inch and half of water depth.

what i do is, when the water reaches the overflow i cover the overflow with plastic kitchen wrap, the suction will pull the plastic tight to the opening. This will buy you some time.  but you **must not do this and walk away from the tub while the water is on**. I an not responsible for any water damage that you cause. i will take credit for your happy toes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many varieties of *waste & overflow* assemblies. You will need to disassemble yours to find out how it works and what the problem is, it is not always easy but if you are ambitious and you persevere I have confidence that you can fix it. Look closely for any manufacturer's name stamped on the overflow plate, it might help you find parts.

[image]

Comment: PS- the wire and plunger setup is commonly referred to as the *bucket and wire assembly*.

Comment: If the linkage becomes disconnected, is it possible to reconnect through the overflow opening in the tub or does one have to have access behind and under the tub.

Comment: You can usually fix it from the opening in the tub (depends on type, if it is like the picture on the left above, I know you can). I have even removed entire bucket and wire assemblies and replaced them that way. It isn't always easy though, you need to fish the wires and bucket up and they get stuck/jammed and crud makes it a fight.

Comment: When I think about the problems with these linkages I am surprised people put in this type of stopper. There are metal stoppers that are operated by hand from the tub side--with a twist it drops down and seals. I put one of these in a lavatory for a relative, then later I went over and it was removed. I was told, " It doesn't work." I found it and put it back on and brightly said, "I put it back on and it works." But I know that the next time I'm over there it will be removed.